# Restrict app installation for particular version of android

Tags: android

I am working on android app. Can anybody tell me that how can we restrict our app installation in android version less than 4.0 from google play developer console.

Comment: You can set the version requirements in the apps manifest https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html

Comment: By setting minimal sdk level in the manifest

Comment: I don't think that google play consol can do it. You need to change minSDK in build.gradle/manifest

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I need to restrict the installation of apps in the Vivo model v2111 models, how can I do that? Also with Samsung M Series. Any way to restrict the brands

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that I know of to manage that in Developer Console. You should upload binary that was packaged with Minimum Android Version set in `AndroidManifest.xml` to what ever is the minimum you still want to support (4.0 in your case).

Example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
</manifest>
```

14 is the API Level of Android 4.0.

Comment: Can I restrict for some models alone. like vivo v2111 or Samsung M series like that

Answer (score 0):

This is not set in `Google Play developer console`, it is set in the project's build gradle.

The setting is in `build.gradle` file in your application module. There should be something like this.

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

change `minSdkVersion` to whatever value of sdk you want to support.

Read more here: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html#minsdkversion

And here are the sdk int value for each Android version: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

Comment: I need to restrict the installation of apps in the Vivo model v2111 models, how can I do that? Also with Samsung M Series